# Can default parameter invoke a object constructor

Tags: c++

In C++, if a function's parameter is an user-define object, can we give it a default value by invoking the object's constructor?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is something you should really try before posting. Also I suggest you check out http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, by the way I should try..

For example:

```
/* Your user-define object */
class A { 
 public:
  A( const int& x = 4) : x_(x) {}
  operator int() {return x_;}
 private: 
  int x_;
}

class B {
 public:
  B( const int& y = A(3)) : y_(y) {}
  /* OR */
  B( A* a = new A(4)) : a_(a) {} 
 private: 
  int y_;
  A* a_;
}
```